# Cascaded find root for membership referer - PHP/MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, cascade

I run membership site and mySQL database field have ID, referid and rootid fields to know
who invited who and who referred who

When new member sign-up, in new member record, i write her invitor member's id in the referid

In turn, A invites B, B invites C, C invites D and D invites E

E has correct field referid as D's id from the database

I want A's id in E's rootid field which is original invitor 
It is like downline building but I could not correctly fillup rootid field with my 3 queries which takes referid of invitor and finds their rootid and set in own rootid field

If I can somehow save tree of invites and downline that will be better

Confused how to proceed from here

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this is what you're describing...

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  refer_id INT UNSIGNED,
  rootrefer_id INT UNSIGNED,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


/*Adam is an original member and was not reffered by anyone.*/
  INSERT INTO members (name) VALUES ('adam');

/*
Barbara is referred by Adam her id = 2
her refer_id, and rootrefer_id = 1
*/
  INSERT INTO members (name, refer_id, rootrefer_id) 
  VALUES('barbara', 1, 1);

/*
Cindy is referred by Barbara her id = 3, 
her refer_id = 2, her rootrefer_id = 1, just like Barbara
*/
  INSERT INTO members (name, refer_id, rootrefer_id)
  VALUES('cindy', 2, 1);

/*
Cindy in turn refers Dan, Dans id = 4
his refer_id = 3, and his rootrefer_id = 1
*/
  INSERT INTO members (name, refer_id, rootrefer_id)
  VALUES ('dan', 3, 1);

/*
Dan invites his pal Eddie, Eds id = 5
his refer_id = 4, and his rootrefer_id also = 1
*/
  INSERT INTO members (name, refer_id, rootrefer_id)
  VALUES ('eddie', 4, 1);
```

You could query this like so:

```
#select original, non-refered members
#SELECT * FROM members WHERE refer_id IS NULL;

#select referred members
#SELECT * FROM members WHERE refer_id IS NOT NULL;

#select all referers and refered
SELECT 
  m1.id AS ref_id, 
  m1.name AS ref_name,
  m2.id AS id,
  m2.name AS name  
  FROM members m1
 JOIN members m2 ON m1.id=m2.refer_id;

#selct all root referers and refered
SELECT 
  m1.id AS root_id, 
  m1.name AS root_name,
  m2.id AS id,
  m2.name AS name  
  FROM members m1
 JOIN members m2 ON m1.id=m2.rootrefer_id;

#select all referers who are also referred, their referers and referred
SELECT
  mrr.id AS referrer_id,
  mrr.name AS referrer_name,
  m.id AS id,
  m.name AS name,
  mrd.id AS refered_id,
  mrd.name AS refered_name
  FROM members m
 JOIN members mrr ON mrr.id=m.refer_id
 JOIN members mrd ON m.id=mrd.refer_id;
```

try it out

Comment: you took lot of trouble, thanks for that but root id is not to be inserted along with new member, it is to be 'found' by processing later - let me explain bit more.  adam invited barbara, barbara invited cindy so 1,adam, <NULL> is first record, second is 2,barbara,1 and third is 3,cindy,2  now we want last record to be 3,cindy,2,1 where as 1 will be taken from barbara's record when we find barbara's parent. cindy's child should also put 1 as root_id as first inviter in this chain was adam (id 1)

Comment: I am going to implement this line : [link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)   - it mathematically keeps track of parents and childs upto _n_th level